# Kappa coefficient, prevalence and bias. How to interpret wide confidence intervals, some falling outside [-1,1]

Tags: confidence-interval, binary-data, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa, method-comparison

I an assessing the agreement between two measurements methods on a binary presence/absence metric.
Here is one example of a contingency table:

```r
> table

          0       1
  0 0.92221 0.04624
  1 0.00916 0.02238
```

I am using epiR to compute Cohen's kappa coefficient, the prevalence index, the bias index and the PABAK coefficient, with associated confidence interval.

```r
epi.kappa(table, method="cohen", alternative="two.sided")
```

Here are the results:

```r
$prop.agree
    obs   exp
1 0.945 0.904

$pindex
  est    se lower upper
1 0.9 0.306   0.3   1.5

$bindex
     est    se  lower upper
1 0.0371 0.307 -0.565 0.639

$pabak
    est  lower upper
1 0.889 -0.962     1

$kappa
    est   se lower upper
1 0.422 2.39 -4.26   5.1

$z
  test.statistic p.value
1          0.177    0.86

$mcnemar
  test.statistic df p.value
1         0.0248  1   0.875
```

I understand how to interpret the estimates in themselves, but I an confused about the very wide confidence intervals and what that means. Also how can the CI for kappa fall outside of [-1;1] ?